# Need to profile using Leaks with ARC enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is there any need any more to profile with Leaks now that we can use ARC (which incidentally is absolutely fantastic and really speeds up development!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should still check your app's memory use, using Leaks and other tools. **ARC is not a panacea.** Your app could still leak memory in a number of ways.

Search SO for "ARC leaks" and you'll find plenty of examples.